# Magento 1.9 Programmatically removing promo items from cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I have a controller that loops through all items in the cart, and removes the item if it matches the condition, in this case all products should be removed because of the `true` as condition.

```
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();

// Loop through products
foreach ($cart->getItems() as $item) {
  if(true) { // Normally a different condition
    $cart->removeItem($item->getItemId());
  }
}
```

The script does remove all items, except for those added as promotional item by a module (Amasty Free Gifts / Promo Items).
The items unique key doesn't change, so it is not being removed from the cart, neither added again by the module, because the key hasn't changed.

When I delete the main item, the promo item came with, the promo item is deleted.

**How can I delete this product?**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == 'promo') {
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();     
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The removeItem() function isn't reached, there are no items with sku 'promo'.