# Magento 1.9 - programmatically removing products from the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, php, quote

I'm trying to replicate the cart on another page and I'm using 'checkout / cart' to retrieve item info, but I need to replicate the remove cart button and I just don't know how. Here's my code example:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}

<a href="" class="remove"><strong>Remove Item cart</strong></a>
```

What is the get url for cart remover?

Answer (score 0):

> $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
> $cartItemId = 123;
> $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($cartItemId)->save();

You can pass Cart Item Id there and it will be remove.

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: How to override "$cartitemId=123" for product code?

Comment: Check this will helps you. : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232850/magento-1-9-programmatically-removing-promo-items-from-cart